# How to add additional claims to ID Token - Azure Government Portal

Tags: azure, azure-gov

I'm trying to overload the OAuth ID Token by adding additional claims. I can already use the Graph API to get the claims that I need but I would like to understand if it's possible to add the additional claims directly into the ID Token? I've updated the manifest by adding the required claims in and then flipping "acceptMappedClaims" to true, however I still don't see these in the ID token. What am I missing?

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
      {
        "name": "employeeid",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": true,
        "additionalProperties": []
      },
      {
        "name": "mail",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": true,
        "additionalProperties": []
      }
    ],
    "accessToken": [],
    "saml2Token": []
  },
  "acceptMappedClaims": true,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on where the ID token is generated from. If it's on-premises AD and federated identity is used take a look at [Customizing the OIDC id_token in ADFS 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/custom-id-tokens-in-ad-fs).

If it's just a cloud identity I'd take a look at the second link jwmiller5 posted or this one: [how-to-set-claims-from-asp-net-openid-connect-owin-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196931/how-to-set-claims-from-asp-net-openid-connect-owin-components).

Hope this helps,
Bernie

Comment: Thanks Bernie, this link goes straight to the answer I was after and I have it working

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that Bruce!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add additional claims into your AD token, you would need Azure AD premium and you can add the values as attributes. See [Claim augmentation with Azure AD authentcation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094227/claim-augmentation-with-azure-ad-authentcation)

If you just need the claims in one particular application, you can add the claims in the app itself. See [Azure AD PostAuthentication add claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682771/azure-ad-postauthentication-add-claims)

Comment: Thanks, it was the second link that I was after, the first one is about SAML which is easily done within the portal